# Trouble with storybook in IE11. "WeakSet is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, storybook, core-js

I have a trouble with running storybook in IE11.
This is the error that I see in IE11 console: [image]

I`m using core-js in babel like that:

```
presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      modules: false,
      loose: true,
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      corejs: 2,
      debug: true,
      targets: {
        browsers: [
          'last 2 Chrome versions',
          'last 2 Firefox versions',
          'last 2 Safari versions',
          'last 2 Opera versions',
          'last 2 Edge versions',
          'last 2 iOS versions',
          'last 2 ChromeAndroid versions',
          'IE 11'
        ]
      }
    }],
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ]
```

This is babel-loader in webpack:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  include: [resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

Tryed it also with core-js@3.6.1, but I`ve got the same result.

UPD: The translation of error: WeakSet is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

For IE11 you have to do a polyfill to get WeakSet working. Check out this repo https://github.com/ungap/weakset

> A polyfill for IE11 or browsers that have a WeakMap, but not a WeakSet.
>
> - CDN via https://unpkg.com/@ungap/weakset
> - ESM via `import WeakSet from '@ungap/weakset'`
> - CJS via `const WeakSet = require('@ungap/weakset')`
>
> Compatible down to IE9, works well with ES5 shim upfront in IE8 (and maybe lower too).

Comment: Tryed it. Then there is a trouble with WeakMap and so on. The problem is that core-js has to fix it, but it doesn`t

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot of solutions, but the only thing that worked for me was an old school script src to the above CDN. In your storybook folder, add a file named `preview-head.html` and add this script link:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/weakset"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular developers, `npm i @ungap/weakset` and import it to `angular.json` under `scripts`.

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/@ungap/weakset/min.js"
],
```

Importing through `polyfills.ts` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

causes an error WeakSet, private instance method

```js
    class some {
    #some() {...}
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).